# Initialization of a For loop with multiple, different data types

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

I noticed something I hadn't realized before about for loops in Java.

For example an int and a long declared **before** the for loop may be initialized inside the initilization block.

```
    int x;
    long y;
    for( x = 1,  y = 2; x < 10 && y < 10; x++, y++) {
        System.out.print(x + ",  " + y );
    }
```

However, those same variables will cause a compiler error if declared **inside** the initialization block.

```
    //DOES NOT COMPILE. 
    for( int x = 1, long y = 2; x < 10 && y < 10; x++, y++) {
        System.out.print(x + ",  " + y );
    }
```

Why is it that multiple variables declared before the initialization block can be of different data types, though variables declared inside the initialization block must be of the same type?

Comment: try this `for( int x = 1, y = 2; x < 10 && y < 10; x++, y++) {
            System.out.print(x + ",  " + y );
        }`

Comment: I know that works ... those are the same 'type'

Comment: @Aominè ~ No... that is not multiple variable *types* in the foor loop initilization block. semantics mate.

Comment: Make them both `int` or both `long` If they can't be the same type, use more statements as you would have to do anywhere else.

Comment: @PeterLawrey ~ Yes sir... However, the question is why the first declaration is allowed but the second fails?

Comment: Unrelated, but declaring and mutating multiple variables isn't really idiomatic of a for loop IMO.

Comment: @StuartLC ~ Good point ;-)

Comment: Because a declaration of a variable is a statement, and you only get one statement as the loop initializer. An assignment is an expression, and you can limit those with the comma within one statement.

Comment: The `for` loop only allows one declared type as everything after the `;` which would normally separate them is the condition and the iterator.

Comment: Theres the answer then ...

Comment: @EddieB if you did read all the answers in the suggested dupe, then you would have seen the answer to your question. semantics mate.

Comment: In the end, it works that way in Java because that's the way it works in C and it works that way in C because that's what made sense to the designers at the time based on what they imaged was the use case for a simple `for` loop.

Comment: This is not  a duplicate.. This is about declaring different data types... not just muliple variables of the same type...

Comment: @EddieB again, the suggested dupe has a question showing `for (Node<T> current = first, int currentIndex; current != null; 
            current = current.next, currentIndex++){...}` , how is that the same type?

Comment: @Aominè ~ I would rather have an authoritative answer as Peter Lawrey provided.

Comment: @EddieB good, then you've got your answer as a comment.

Comment: @Aominè ~ Cool... it was really a language design question mate...

Comment: Duplicate explains it using Java Language Specification so I don't see how is it not authoritative. JSL clearly states that basic for loop is defined as `for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) StatementNoShortIf` where `ForInit` can be either `StatementExpressionList` (which explains why `for( x = 1,  y = 2;` works fine) OR `LocalVariableDeclaration` which is defined as `{VariableModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorList` so it expects only one type and possibly list of arguments. So `int x, int y` is wrong (not to mention when types are different) but `int a, b, c[]) is fine.